# Windows Image Backup and the Vanishing Old Backup

Tags: windows-7, windows-7-backup

Context:

- Windows 7 32-bit edition
- Big external drive for holding system images

I've noticed that even when there's plenty of space (say, several hundred GBs of free space), when I make a new system image, Windows wipes out the old image. I deduce this by looking at the name of the folder on the drive. This might be the wrong way to check.

How do I get Windows to keep the old backup? I'd prefer to take advantage of incremental backups to save space; I know that I can copy the entire backup folder but that's a quick way to consume tons of hard drives.